# Unable to download PDF using chrome in python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, pdf, download

I am using selenium in python. When I click on the first PDF icon visible on the page. Instead of the PDF file being downloaded there is a page with "Open" button on it. I have tried clicking on the open button using ID open-button but it does not seem to work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs={"download.default_directory":"C:\\path",
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
"download.directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe',options=options)

driver.get('https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/conhome/10067248/proceeding?isnumber=10067251&sortType=vol-only-seq&rowsPerPage=75&pageNumber=1')
cookie_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'cc-btn')
cookie_button.click()

time.sleep(20)
pdf_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label='PDF']")

for button in pdf_buttons:
    button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    button.click()
    driver.back()
    break

time.sleep(1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the Open button is inside an iframe, that page particularly has 2 iframes. Try do it like this, switch to the second iframe, which has the button, and then click on it

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs={"download.default_directory":"C:\\path",
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
"download.directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe',options=options)

driver.get('https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/conhome/10067248/proceeding?isnumber=10067251&sortType=vol-only-seq&rowsPerPage=75&pageNumber=1')
cookie_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'cc-btn')
cookie_button.click()

time.sleep(20)
pdf_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label='PDF']")[0].click()

# for button in pdf_buttons:
#     button.click()
#     time.sleep(5)
#     button.click()
#     driver.back()
#     break

time.sleep(20)


driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"iframe")[1])


open_button = driver.find_element(By.ID,"open-button")
open_button.click()

time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried switching to an iframe but for some reason it did not worked. But your code worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code, which uses ChromeOptions to disable the PDF download prompt in Chrome. I have also modified your code to use explicit wait for elements. When we click on a PDF download button, it will open a new page with the download option. We then switch to the iframe with the download button, click on it to download the file and wait for 5 sec for it to complete

In the given code, after downloading a PDF and coming back to the original page, the code re-fetches the list of links with the label "PDF". This is done to update the list of links on the page as the previously downloaded PDF link will not be present anymore in the DOM and the stale element exception will occur if we try to access it again.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences = {
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
    "download.open_pdf_in_system_reader": False,
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "download.default_directory": "your download folder path here"
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get(
    'https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/conhome/10067248/proceeding?isnumber=10067251&sortType=vol-only-seq&rowsPerPage=75&pageNumber=1')
cookie_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'cc-btn')
cookie_button.click()
time.sleep(20)
pdf_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label='PDF']")
for i in range(len(pdf_buttons)):
    # Click on the link
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(pdf_buttons[i]))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", pdf_buttons[i])
    pdf_buttons[i].click()
    frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@src]")))
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
    down = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href]")))
    down.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.back()
    pdf_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label='PDF']")
# Re-fetch the list of links
```